# PrimeNG Schedule/FullCalendar showing extra row of days

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am using PrimeNG's "Schedule", which uses FullCalendar. It is working fine other than the fact that it is showing an extra row of days, as seen in this image:

[image]

I like that it shows March 1-4 and fades those days out, but the extra row showing days 5-11 isn't needed and is taking up extra space. Going to other months does the same thing. Is there an easy way to prevent it from showing an extra row of dates like this?

Comment: That's the proper behavior to fullcalendar because of this propertie:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/fixedWeekCount/

Comment: Yup, that was it. Adding [fixedWeekCount]="false" to my <p-schedule> tag in my HTML fixed the problem for me. Feel free to add that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I have responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the proper behavior to fullcalendar because of this propertie:

[fixedWeekCount](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/fixedWeekCount)